# Uncaught ReferenceError: jasmineRequire is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm having a problem with my test, when I run them I'm getting this error:

```
09 09 2015 14:55:27.174:INFO [Chrome 45.0.2454 (Mac OS X 10.10.1)]: Connected on socket 9aXAoBK8a1zKw9IVAAAA with id 22794373
Chrome 45.0.2454 (Mac OS X 10.10.1) ERROR
Uncaught ReferenceError: jasmineRequire is not defined
at /Users/agarcia/Projects/affiliate-suite/node_modules/karma/jasmine/lib/boot.js:15
```

this is my karma.conf.js file:

```
/*global __dirname*/
// Karma configuration

var path = require('path');

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: __dirname,

        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js',
            'src/**/*.test.js'
        ],

        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [],

        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {
            'node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js': ['webpack'],
            'src/**/*.test.js': ['webpack']
        },

        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['progress'],

        // web server port
        port: 9876,

        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,

        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: true,

        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: ['Chrome'],

        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: false,

        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-webpack')
        ]
  });
};
```

I have installed:

- "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
- "karma": "^0.13.9",
- "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.0",
- "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
- "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",

Any clue of what's happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading this was the key to find the solution to this problem:

http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/boot.html

It says `jasmine.js` and `jasmine-html.js` have to be load before the `boot.js`, so what I did was to put them in order, it didn't work at all but I looked into the jasmine-core folder and I found a file called `jasmine-core.js` which loads everything in the right order.

It works perfectly!

Comment: And soooo... What did you do with that file?

Comment: What Tim Autin said ^^^. What's the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Put the jasmine files in this order

1. /jasmine.css
2. /jasmine.js
3. /jasmine-html.js

followed by:

4. /boot.js

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
preprocessors: {
  'node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js': [
    'webpack'
  ],
  'src/**/*.test.js': ['webpack']
},
```

to:

```
preprocessors: {
  'src/**/*.test.js': ['webpack']
},
```

`jasmine` will be existing as `global variables`.